# Advance navigation in selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i have the following HTML

```
  <div id="element1">welcome</div>
  <div>username</div>
```

Now the problem is, i have to select the next div element next to "element1". I know,i can build xpath from their parent. But it i need to pick one which is very next to an element. How it is possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [the `following-sibling` axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

This selects all sibling `<div>` elements after the `element1` node:

```
id('element1')/following-sibling::div
```

This selects the first sibling `<div>` element after the `element1` node:

```
id('element1')/following-sibling::div[1]
```

This selects the first sibling node after the `element1` node iff it's a `<div>` element:

```
id('element1')/following-sibling::*[1][local-name(.)='div']
```

All those three examples will select your element (and maybe some more if there are any more matching), so pick one which suits your intent the most.

---

Note that you can do all this with [a simple CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators), too. It's equivalent to the last XPath. And it will be faster.

```css
#element1 + div
```

Comment: @Babai Yes. `following-sibling::*[1][local-name(.)='div']` takes the first following sibling and then tests if the node name is `div`.

Comment: Yes.. that means I am slowly now getting `xpath` a bit.. :)

Comment: @Slanec, is `following-sibling::div[1]` and `following-sibling::*[1][local-name(.)='div']` are same in my case right?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Yes, it's the same in your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `following-sibling`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element1")).findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::div"));
```